# Robolectric+Eclipse Can't find resources?

Tags: android, eclipse, junit4, robolectric

I just configured a test project for my Android app to use Robolectric.
I followed the [Eclipse Quick Start](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/eclipse-quick-start.html).
An exception is raised executing my simple very first test.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.init(ResourceLoader.java:93)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.getStringValue(ResourceLoader.java:271)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getString(ShadowResources.java:56)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java)
    at org.xxx.mobile.android.teldir.app.TelephoneDirectoryTest.searchButtonLabelShouldBeGo(TelephoneDirectoryTest.java:22)
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.StringResourceLoader.getValue(StringResourceLoader.java:17)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.StringArrayResourceLoader.processNode(StringArrayResourceLoader.java:39)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.XpathResourceXmlLoader.processResourceXml(XpathResourceXmlLoader.java:27)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.DocumentLoader.loadResourceXmlFile(DocumentLoader.java:58)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.DocumentLoader.loadResourceXmlDir(DocumentLoader.java:52)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.DocumentLoader.loadResourceXmlDir(DocumentLoader.java:39)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.loadValueResourcesFromDir(ResourceLoader.java:142)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.loadValueResourcesFromDirs(ResourceLoader.java:136)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.loadValueResources(ResourceLoader.java:109)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.init(ResourceLoader.java:85)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.getStringValue(ResourceLoader.java:271)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getString(ShadowResources.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.methodInvoked(ShadowWrangler.java:87)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.methodInvoked(RobolectricInternals.java:110)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java)
    [...]
```

The test follows.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class TelephoneDirectoryTest {
    private TelephoneDirectory activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        activity = new TelephoneDirectory();
    }

    @Test
    public void searchButtonLabelShouldBeGo() throws Exception {
        String goLabel = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.search);
        assertEquals("Go", goLabel);

    }
}
```

It seems it can't find Android `./res` folder. I pointed the JUnit configuration to `${workspace_loc:teldir-android}` as the guide says. And this makes Eclipse to find the `AndroidManifest.xml`, avoiding other errors, imho.

Trying to avoid this exception I also added `./res` folder as source folder of my Android app, cleaned and relaunched all, but the same exception raised.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can also try this with maven. Here's the sample code: https://github.com/pivotal/RobolectricSample

Comment: can you paste your import code

Comment: @Sunil Just pasted my imports

Comment: have you gotten any farther with this? I am experiencing this exact error.

Comment: @ahsteele No good news about it, not even from Robolectric Google Group :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to add an environment variable to my test run configuration:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:/path/to/android-sdks
```

Comment: This is what worked for me in Intellij. I had the env variable all set up...guess i just needed to add the reference in the build config. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue (RuntimeException when loading the resources) when first setting up my Eclipse project with Robolectric but now it works.

I figured two things out:

- If you receive a `WARNING: Unable to find path to Android SDK` (the message might not be displayed in a version lower than 1.0-RC1) then `ResourceLoader` failed to find your SDK root. One of the methods looks for an `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable that should point to where your Android SDK resides.
- Finally, there is a [bug](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/issues/75) which causes an exception if your menu.xml is not formatted in a certain way.

Using Robolectric without Maven or Ant is possible but there might be a few more bugs. [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZGSWCj0KPw) video shows the correct project setup. If it doesn't work, get the latest version from Github (import as a Maven project in Eclipse and you might need *github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer*) and start debugging!

Answer (score 1):

If the ResourceNotFound only occurs for string arrays defined with `<array>...</array>` tags, replace them with `<string-array>...</string-array>`

Using robolectric 2.0

read in: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/gQoY0bCguYs

docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Answer (score 0):

Its wrong obviously..I had to setup an ant way to do things as you cannot launch robolectric tests from eclipse as the Eclipse workspace still does not recognize linked-source individual files properly..see my alpha example:

https://github.com/shareme/Wabash

Same error that I get by the way..from the Pivotal Labs directions..

Comment: Are you saying that not doing as in Wabash (not seen yet), the only way I have is to put a ./test folder for tests directly in the same Android project, as in RoboletricSample? If so, I think I could do it...

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem after doing a fresh install of Windows 8. Most likely Robolectric cannot find the SDK. In order to point it to the right place. You can generate a `local.properties` file in your Android project. This can be done in the command line by going to the root folder of your project and issuing the command:

```
android update project –p c:\project\root\folder
```

Open `local.properties` to verify the `sdk.dir` is pointing to the expected path.

Also make sure you have downloaded android API level 8. Robolectric looks for a folder in the `/path/to/your/sdk/platforms/android-8` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Jar file in this link.just download it. add JAR in project
thats it.i have used in my project. Any doubts ask me

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/robolectric/robolectric-1.2-8.jar.zip