# Robolectric "WARNING: Unable to find path to Android SDK"

Tags: android, maven, robolectric

I am using Robolectric without using maven to build, meaning I am using the Robolectric-with-dependencies Jar.

I set it up based on instructions on Robolectric's site, yet I am still getting the WARNING: Unable to find path to Android SDK" error.  I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340239/robolectriceclipse-cant-find-resources) (the first answer) which mentions where the problem is coming from but doesn't answer how I can fix this problem.

I am new and never posted because I can usually find a solution after browsing for awhile, however I had no luck finding the solution.  Anything would help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure to set the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to point to your Android SDK installation, e.g.:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r15
```

Comment: what is the /r15 at the end?  for me would I just say export ANDROID_HOME=/home/robert/android-sdk-linux ?

Comment: that would be fine... if that is the root folder of your sdk install

Comment: in my case multiple platforms are stored under the android-sdk folder. as Manfred said, just make sure that it points to the root of the android SDK you want to use.

Answer (score -2):

Stefan is correct.

More information can be found in my [chapter about Android development with Maven](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-intro.html) as well as the [plugin wiki](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted) and [documentation for the sdk configuration](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/run-mojo.html#sdk). I would also recommend to use the latest version of the android maven plugin as well as the Android SDK..

Comment: I am sorry I am still a newbie to the programming world.  Can you explain the benefits of using Maven for android as if I were five?

Comment: It is like Ruby on Rails for build tools. Convention over configuration, using plugins for various aspects, automatic dependency management, declarative rather than procedural, most widely used build system for Java software, excellent IDE support..