# Robolectric 1.2 : “WARNING: Unable to find path to Android SDK”

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I used

> Robolectric 1.1 jar-with-dependencies

in my project and succeed to get it work, however when I changed the jar to

> 1.2-SNAPSHOT jar-with-dependencies

I get the following warning:

> WARNING: Unable to find path to Android SDK

1. Both jars downloaded from [Sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~robolectric) (I didn't use maven).
2. I tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352903/robolectric-warning-unable-to-find-path-to-android-sdk) question and still get the warning.

Comment: Robolectric is a smart project but IMO it is still in a experimental stage. I had similar problem in 0.9 - 1.0 - 1.1 upgrade, it always break my working code here or there. However, it is open-source so feel free to report bug and contribute to it.

Comment: Thank you, it is really smart, but there is still a lot work to do :(

Answer (score 3):

After I followed this [tutorial](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/eclipse-quick-start.html), I had the same issue. This is how I solved it on my mac:

1- Add Android sdk dir to the bash_profile, first open the file:

```
sudo vim ~/.bash_profile
```

then add the following line: (remember to replace YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH_HERE' with the android SDK file path (e.g. /Users/xxx/development/android-sdk-mac_x86))

```
export ANDROID_HOME=YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH_HERE
```

2- Create a file called local.properties in the root dir of your Android project, and add the following line:  (remember to replace YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH_HERE' with the android SDK file path (e.g. /Users/xxx/development/android-sdk-mac_x86))

```
  sdk.dir=YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH_HERE
```